# Pandas - creating a rolling percentage within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas.
I have a dataframe of Horse results, that looks like this(only much bigger):

```
    Horses        RaceDate Position
1   RedHorse      1/2/00   2
2   BlueHorse     1/2/00   6
3   YellowHorse   1/2/00   7
4   RedHorse      15/1/00  1
5   RedHorse      1/1/00   5
```

For each entry I want to work out the win percentage going back to the first time that horse ran. Something like this:

```
    Horses        RaceDate Position WinPercentage
1   RedHorse      1/2/00   2        50%    
2   BlueHorse     1/2/00   6        0%
3   YellowHorse   1/2/00   7        0%
4   RedHorse      15/1/00  5        100%
5   RedHorse      1/1/00   1        0%
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how you are actually calculating the Win percentage, are you calculating based on the position for each row?

Comment: Of course @Sumanth, I want to calculate the win percentage based on every race prior to the creation of that row. So all the entries for RedHorse above are based on the number of wins prior to that race. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Win per horse**

```
df2 = df.copy(deep=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2 = df2.sort_values('RaceDate')
df2['win'] = np.where(df2.Position == 1, 1, 0)
df2['win_count'] = df2.groupby(['Horses'])['win'].cumsum()
df2['race_count'] = df2.groupby(['Horses'])['win_count'].cumsum()
df2['WinPercentage'] = df2['win_count'] / df2['race_count'] * 100
df2 = df2.sort_index()
print(df2)
```

*output:*

```
   index       Horses   RaceDate  Position  win  win_count  race_count  WinPercentage
0      1     RedHorse 2000-02-01         2    0          1           2           50.0
1      2    BlueHorse 2000-02-01         6    0          0           0            NaN
2      3  YellowHorse 2000-02-01         7    0          0           0            NaN
3      4     RedHorse 2000-01-15         1    1          1           1          100.0
4      5     RedHorse 2000-01-01         5    0          0           0            NaN
```

**Win per row**

```
df1 = df.copy(deep=True)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1 = df1.sort_values(['RaceDate', 'index'])
df1['win'] = np.where(df1.Position == 1, 1, 0)
df1['win'] = df1.win.ffill()
df1['win_count'] = df1.win.cumsum()
df1['race_count'] = df1.win_count.cumsum()
df1['WinPercentage'] = df1['win_count'] / df1['race_count'] * 100
print(df1)
```

*output:*

```
   index       Horses   RaceDate  Position  win  win_count  race_count  WinPercentage
4      5     RedHorse 2000-01-01         5    0          0           0            NaN
3      4     RedHorse 2000-01-15         1    1          1           1     100.000000
0      1     RedHorse 2000-02-01         2    0          1           2      50.000000
1      2    BlueHorse 2000-02-01         6    0          1           3      33.333333
2      3  YellowHorse 2000-02-01         7    0          1           4      25.000000
```

**Concatenation of the 2 dataframes**

```
dfFinal = df1[['index', 'Horses', 'RaceDate', 'WinPercentage']].merge(df2[['index', 'Horses', 'RaceDate', 'WinPercentage']], on=['index', 'Horses', 'RaceDate'], how='outer')
print(dfFinal)
```

*output:*

```
   index       Horses   RaceDate  WinPercentage_x  WinPercentage_y
0      5     RedHorse 2000-01-01              NaN              NaN
1      4     RedHorse 2000-01-15       100.000000            100.0
2      1     RedHorse 2000-02-01        50.000000             50.0
3      2    BlueHorse 2000-02-01        33.333333              NaN
4      3  YellowHorse 2000-02-01        25.000000              NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
This would give the win percentage for each horse.
Is it possible to get the percentage for each row, looking retrospectively. So in the example above, the RedHorse percentage changes with each new entry.

Comment: What will be the output ?

Comment: A new column of win percentages, but it would show the win percentage correct up to the time that row was entered. So in the RedHorse example above it shows the win percentage for the races prior to that row. Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I shifted the results +1, as this gave the percentage after the results of this race and I wanted it for prior. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to sort by date, group by horse, and then take the cumulative mean of their wins at each date?

```
df['WonRace'] = df['Position'] == 1
df.sort_values('RaceDate').groupby('Horses')['WonRace'].expanding().mean()
```